# How to remove "WaveShare" DRM add-on from Firefox

Tags: firefox, drm

I stupidly allowed Firefox to play DRM content, and now I have an add-on named "WaveShare" DRM player permanently embedded in Firefox.  I'm not happy to have a google binary blob running in my web browser.

I wish to permanently and veritably remove the add-on.

- I am asking about a Firefox **add-on** not an extension.
- I know it I can click a button to somehow/possibly "disable" it.

Background:

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, with Firefox installed via snap.  Allowing DRM playback did not need root permission, so it must be installed somewhere inside my home directory.

Mozilla support supposedly has pages on this:

- https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/disable-or-remove-add-ons
- https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1140262

But these pages do only specify how to remove an "extension" or "theme", not an "add-on".

Other web pages do specify how to remove an add-on, but these are old, and show add-ons that seem to have a "remove" feature.  The remove feature has been removed.

EDIT:

So far I've searched for the module with:

```
find . -type f  | while read file; do strings "$file" | grep -i waveshare; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo "### $file"; fi; done
```

Comment: There is no Firefox add-on called "waveshare"  among the supported add-on listings (https://addons.mozilla.org/) so it's not clear what was added or where it came from. Since it's not a supported Firefox add-on from a reputable source, your re-install method seems wise.

Comment: @user535733 - I'm pretty sure (99%) Firefox downloaded and installed it.  It must be from some secret repository.

Comment: Since Firefox is 100% Open Source code, I gently suggest that folks are quite sure of their facts before accusing Mozilla of "secret" repositories and other nefarious activities. There may be other (unsupported) possibilities.

Comment: @user535733 - Agreed.  But I will also point out that a lot of their income comes from google.  Ref: https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=firefox+funded+by+google&ia=web

Answer (score 0):

A sub-optimal workaround: *re-install*

Warning: This procedure outlines how to backup Firefox bookmarks and saved-logins.  Other settings will be lost.

**Export Save Logins to .CSV:**
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/export-login-data-firefox

**Export Bookmarks to .JSON**
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/export-firefox-bookmarks-to-backup-or-transfer

**Make a note of plugins used:**
NoScript, Ublock Origin, Privacy Badger, Video Download Helper...

**Remove Firefox**

```
sudo snap remove --purge firefox

echo "Warning: this next command may remove cinnamon-desktop-environment too, careful"
sudo apt-get remove --purge firefox
```

**Remove Firefox User-data for the local user**

```
if [ -d “$HOME/snap/firefox” ]; then rm -r “$HOME/snap/firefox”; fi
if [ -d “$HOME/.mozilla” ]; then rm -r “$HOME/.mozilla”; fi
```

**Re-install Firefox**

```
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

Re-configure, Re-install add-extensions.

Re-starting firefox shows the DRM add-on is gone.